# RadioListTile don't change selected

Tags: flutter, dart

*This code fetches the data and applies it to the radiobutton, but it cannot be modified*

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var filteredItem = ProList.firstWhere((element)=> element.idPush == idC, orElse: () =>null);
  
    String license = filteredItem.license;
    int _license= int.parse(license);
  

    RadioListTile<dynamic> buildRadioListLicense(val, txt) {
        return RadioListTile(
            controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
            activeColor: myRed,
            value: val,
            groupValue: _license,
            onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                    _license = value;
                });
            },
            title: Text(txt),
        );
    }

    return Scaffold(
        body:Row(
            mainAxisAlignment:
            MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
                Expanded(
                    child: buildRadioListLicense(
                        1, getTranslated(context, 'received')),
                ),
                Expanded(
                    child: buildRadioListLicense(
                        2, getTranslated(context, 'inProgress')),
                ),
                Expanded(
                    child: buildRadioListLicense(
                        3, getTranslated(context, 'done')),
                )
            ],
        ), 
    );
}
```

Comment: what cannot be modified?

Comment: i want to change on this radioButton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "checked" attriubute inside of your builder.

docs: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RadioListTile-class.html

**Update**

Ok I know what is wrong. Your `_license` variable should not be inside of `Widget builder`. Whenever builder recreates itself  `_license` always come back to its initial value and since `groupValue` decides which element is active it doesnt update.

Comment: please correct your code to be reproduceable

Comment: @eslam here it is